# Swift 4 extension function on generic protocol which takes a generic function as parameter

Tags: swift, generics

```
swift --version
Swift version 4.1 (swift-4.1-RELEASE)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Given a simple protocol which defines a generic producer (Source):

```
protocol Source {
    associatedtype T

    func produce() -> T
}
```

And a mapping capable of converting between source types:

```
struct Mapping<T, U : Source> : Source {
    typealias Transformation = (U.T) -> T

    private let upstream : U
    private let block : Transformation

    init(_ upstream: U, _ block : @escaping Transformation) {
        self.upstream = upstream
        self.block = block
    }

    func produce() -> T {
        return block(upstream.produce())
    }
}
```

And a sample source which produces static text:

```
struct TextSource : Source {
    private let text : String

    init(_ text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }

    func produce() -> String {
        return text
    }
}
```

I can use this to, e.g., count characters...

```
let t = TextSource("Hi!")
let f = Mapping(t, { (text: String) -> Int in
    return text.count
})

print(f.produce()) // output: 3
```

But I'd rather like to use a generic `map` extension function on `Source` such that transformations can be chained, e.g.:

```
let t = TextSource("Hi!").map { (text: String) -> Int in
    return text.count
}
```

**Approach A**

```
extension Source {
    func map<T, U : Source>(_ block: @escaping Mapping<T, U>.Transformation) -> Source {
        return Mapping(self, block)
    }
}
```

That is rejected by the swift compiler:

```
error: generic parameter 'U' is not used in function signature
    func map<T, U : Source>(_ block: @escaping Mapping<T, U>.Transformation) -> Source {
                ^
```

**Approach B**

```
extension Source {
    func map<T>(_ block: @escaping Mapping<T, U>.Transformation) -> Source {
        return Mapping(self, block)
    }
}
```

In this case the compiler complains about the missing type parameter:

```
error: use of undeclared type 'U'
    func map<T>(_ block: @escaping Mapping<T, U>.Transformation) -> Source {
                                              ^
```

**Question**

Which type parameters and constraints need to be specified on the `map` extension function in order to satisfy the compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `Source` as a concrete return type for `map` because it is a protocol with an associated type requirement.

To solve this, you can have the `map` function return `Mapping<X, Self>`:

```
extension Source {
    func map<Result>(_ transform: @escaping (T) -> Result) -> Mapping<Result, Self> {
        return Mapping(self, transform)
    }
}
```

The function now has a `Self` requirement. The resulting `Mapping` type has a generic type parameter `Self` that is replaced by the concrete implementation of `Source`, e.g. `Mapping` or `TextSource`.

Comment: Right, thanks a lot. That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: In Swift 5.1 it is possible to specify an opaque result type (i.e., `-> some Source` instead of `-> Mapping<Result, Self>`. Do you mind updating/extending your answer?

Comment: Note that opaque return types come with some limitations. If you have `some Source`, you will lose type information for the associated type `T`, so you can't really do anything with it. `TextSource("Hi!").map {$0.count}.map {$0 + 42}` for example will no longer compile, because in the second closure, it is no longer possible to know what `T` refers to. So I don't think `some Source` is a good solution here. When Swift gets generalized existentials, it may be possible to do something like this though.